# prestashop 1.7.6.4 webservice POST api request error 405 invalid

Tags: api, web-services, get, http-post, prestashop-1.7

I have a problem with webservice api request on my Prestashop 1.7.6.4 witch PHP Version 7.2.28 .

I setting webservice  POST ON for charts and order .

On test website (same file, setting and server) all work fine

On Live web site have reply  : "  [CDATA[Method GET is not allowed for the resource carts with this authentication key]]"

Like this Picture : 
[test with https://app.boomerangapi.com/?ext google chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGTRj.jpg)

Why call POST and reply GET error ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old, but you have to activate the method for the ws_key you are using.
to do so you have to :
1/ Login to your back-office
2/ Go to advanced parameters at the bottom of the left menu
3/ Go to web-services at the bottom
4/ Click edit on your web-service key
5/ Tick the box correspondent to the method you want (get,post,put)
6/ Save